# Dell inspiron 11 3162 | Ubuntu 14.04 | Failure to Boot after install

Tags: boot, uefi, dell, bios

All:

We've been experiencing an issue with Ubuntu 14.04 on the install of a Dell Inspiron 11 3162 which per Ubuntu is certified (https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201511-20043/).

The pastebin is below we've exceeded 15 combinations of install but we always get a failure to find OS during the bootup. Your help would be GREAT as I'm at my wits end on this.

Pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23487594/

Thanks

The steps we've taken:

1. Installed the OS while in UEFI  and Legacy (same results).
2. gParted and formatted the disk prior to OS load (same results)
3. Followed the steps outlined on ([Dell Inspiron 11 3000 series (3162) won't bool after ubuntu installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806151/dell-inspiron-11-3000-series-3162-wont-bool-after-ubuntu-installation)) as well as booted to a live USB and tried to resolve.
4. During Install have completed all actions "Erase disk" "Install along side", have used and not used LVM and have tried to complete "Something Else" to create partitions.
5. Have burned a CD and connected an external drive to install as well as used a USB stick.
6. Have connected/not connected to wifi and a USB dongle for RJ45 LAN connectivity.